# Meaning of "Tea leaves are a challenge to read."

Tags: meaning-in-context

From [CNBC.com](http://www.CNBC.com/2017/03/01/saudi-Aramco-listing-who-will-win-the-worlds-biggest-IPO.html?__source=google%7Ceditorspicks%7C&par=google&google_editors_picks=true):

> **But the tea leaves about Saudi Aramco's current leanings are apparently a challenge to read**, with several well-placed experts telling CNBC that New York is either a complete shoo-in for the listing — or it stands absolutely no chance because of regulation and geopolitical concerns.

Does the bold part of the sentence above mean "predicting the future of Aramco by looking at its current tendencies is apparently a challenge"?

Comment: [TEA LEAF READING (TASSEOGRAPHY)](http://www.unexplainedstuff.com/Prophecy-and-Divination/Tea-Leaf-Reading-Tasseography.html) *A centuries-old method of divining the future involves the interpretation of the fragments of tea leaves at the bottom of a client's cup.*

Comment: "Tea leaves **about**" is straining the metaphor.

Answer (score 6):

**Not exactly.**

It refers to the old practice of divining the future by looking for patterns in used tea leaves. In modern usage, it refers to attempting to predict the outcome of a situation by careful examination of various factors, with the implication that the prediction is quite tentative.

In this case, it's saying "Predictions about Aramco's future are completely unreliable", with the added implication that those making these predictions are just guessing but making a pretence of rational analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Leaf curl is a natural response to rise in barometric pressure, which is a sign of rain to come. The tea leaves on the tree, not in a cup, were very important for people to anticipate sowing seeds for harvest.

Comment: Interesting. Your answer differs from the other explanations given. Can you add references to back up your claim?